# School program tests not covering my code correctly and I'm not sure why

Tags: c

This might be inappropriate but I'm working on a school project in university and we use an automated test service called Web-Cat. When I upload my file (everything is correct as for the filename and method names etc.) the tests throw this at me:

```
hint: your code/tests do not correctly cover error: Cannot locate behavioral analysis output.
```

My code looks like this, I can't find any compile errors or anything that would cause such a problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
double getPositiveAverage(double array[], int numItems)
{
    double average = 0;
    int numOfItems = 0;
    for (int i = numItems-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (array[i] > 0)
        {
            average = average + array[i];
            numOfItems++;
        }
    }
    if (numOfItems == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return average / numOfItems;
    }
}
int countRangeValues(double array[], int numItems, double count)
{
    double countPlus = count + .5;
    double countMinus = count - .5;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = numItems-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ((array[i] >= countMinus) && (array[i] < countPlus))
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
double getMaxAbsolute(double array[], int numItems)
{
    double max = 0;
    for (int i = numItems-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (array[i] == max * -1 && array[i] > 0)
        {
            max = array[i];
        }
        else if (array[i] < 0)
        {
            if (max < 0)
            {
                if ((array[i] * -1) > (max * -1))
                {
                    max = array[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((array[i] * -1) > max)
                {
                    max = array[i];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (max < 0)
            {
                if ((array[i]) > (max * -1))
                {
                    max = array[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((array[i]) > max)
                {
                    max = array[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
int countInverses(int array[], int numItems)
{
    int negarray[numItems];
    int negItems = 0;
    int posarray[numItems];
    int posItems = 0;

    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = numItems-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (array[i] < 0)
        {
            negarray[negItems] = array[i];
            negItems++;
        }
        else if(array[i] > 0)
        {
            posarray[posItems] = array[i];
            posItems++;
        }
    }
    if (posItems == 0 || negItems == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (posItems > negItems)
        {
            for (int i = posItems-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = negItems-1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    if ((negarray[j]*-1) == posarray[i] && negarray[j] != 0)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        negarray[j] = 0;
                        posarray[i] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
int getMaxCount(double array[], int numItems)
{
    return countRangeValue(array, numItems, getMaxAbsolute(array, numItems));
}
```

If necessary, I can explain the purpose of all of these methods but the test also says "Your program failed before running any tests. Usually this is a compile problem or premature exit problem. Make sure your program compiles and runs before uploading." So I assume its syntax a compiling problem, I just don't know if anything I did would cause something like that.

Comment: You have a typo in `getMaxCount`. You forgot an 's' when you called the function 'countRangeValue'. You also try to define an array  of dynamic size, this is not allowed in C or atleast not like you to do. `numItems` in your function `countInverses` must be a constant value.

Comment: Where is the `main` function?

Comment: @fussel: The C standard certainly does allow variable length arrays. It is an implementation option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Candidate problems:

1. Compilation error [@fussel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004062/school-program-tests-not-covering-my-code-correctly-and-im-not-sure-why/53005028#comment92912559_53004062)

   ```
     // return countRangeValue(array, numItems, getMaxAbsolute(array, numItems));
        return countRangeValues(array, numItems, getMaxAbsolute(array, numItems));
   ```
2. Missing `main()`  [@Bob__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004062/school-program-tests-not-covering-my-code-correctly-and-im-not-sure-why/53005028#comment92912786_53004062).
3. [Variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99) are OK [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004062/school-program-tests-not-covering-my-code-correctly-and-im-not-sure-why/53005028#comment92918493_53004062) in C99 and optionally in C11 yet do not attempt without insuring a positive array size.

   ```
   int countInverses(int array[], int numItems) {
     if (numItems <= 0) {
       return 0;
     }
     int negarray[numItems];
     ....
   ```
4. Instead of `if (posItems > negItems) {` I'd expect `if (posItems >= negItems) {` or maybe even `if (1)`, yet the goal of `countInverses()` lacks details for deep analysis.
5. `countRangeValues(..., double count)` is suspicious with `double count`.  When `count` is a large value, `countPlus == count` and `countMinus == count`.  The function always returns 0 as `array[i] >= countMinus) && (array[i] < countPlus)` is always false.

---

OP's `getMaxAbsolute()` looks too convoluted.  Suggested alternative:

```
double getMaxAbsolute(const double array[], int numItems) {
  double max = 0.0;
  double amax = 0.0;
  for (int i = numItems - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    double aelement = fabs(array[i]);
    // If greater       or the same, favor + over -
    if (aelement > amax || (aelement == amax && array[i] > max)) {
      max = array[i];
      amax = aelement;
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```

Comment: I realized my IDE hadn't been checking that file for syntax errors, and among the other problems I forgot an s. Feeling pretty stupid but I really appreciate the help!